# Dynamically create pages/activity in Android?

Tags: android, blogs

Okay, so i just created an activity that queries post titles from a database and post it on a view using an adapter.

I would like to implement the following:

- Once I click the title, I should be taken to a separate page/activity that displays the content section of that title. Similar to a blog app that goes to a blog post when we click on the title.

I'm going through a block right now. How does one get this done?

Comment: You just need to implement `Explicit Intent`.

Answer (score 0):

In `Intent` you can use add extra e.g id from each:

**First:** and in activity you can change it Dynamically `setContentView(xxx);`

xxx: change depend on extra you add previously

**Second:** you can create standard layout and depend on extra you can fill
            e.g id==1 ===> fill textview to "zzzz"
                id==2 ===> fill textview to "mmmm"
                ... and so on

Answer (score 0):

Well actually you're not dynamically creating an activity. The content of your second (detail) activity just depends on the user's input on the first activity.

As soon as the user click's on a title on your first activity, you create a new intent and append the post's to the intent's extras.

When you startup your second activity using this intent, you will be able to get the post's id from the extras and load the content from your database.

**FirstActivity**

```
Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
i.putExtra("POST_ID", <post_id>);
startActivity(i);
```

**SecondActivity**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.second);
   Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
   String postId;
   if(bundle != null) {
      // process your id.
      postId = bundle.getString("POST_ID");
    }
}
```